# Theme.Light doesn't work on android API level 9

Tags: android, themes

I made my android app using the Holo.Light theme. I have the icons that look nice on the Holo.Light on a real device with API level 17, in the emulator it also works on API level 8, but when I try it on an older phone with API level 9 on it, I can hardly see the icons because the menu button's background is dark, although I believe I set it up to be light.

styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>
</resources>
```

values-v11/styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    </style>
</resources>
```

and the beginning of my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<application android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

I also have android-support-v4.jar, although I'm not sure it is necessary at all for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just cannot know what the manufacturer did to `Theme.Light`. As of Android 4 the Holo themes are guaranteed not to be changed by the Manufacturer if Google Play runs on the device (I think the protection works by Google Play refusing to run if it detects a change).

Before Android 4 there was no such guarantee for any theme, so the manufacturer could have decided to make arbitrary changes to the original `Theme.Light` such as changing the background for menu buttons. The fact that your app works in an emulator supports this theory.

Install "API Demos" on that device to see what the themes really look like (see `android-sdk/samples/android-17/ApiDemos`).

In addition to extending from `Theme.Light` you should specify explicit values for all styles that are important for your app (which is tedious) or go for HoloEverywhere like Eric Zhang suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Holo was not included until the later versions of Android, so you can't use it on older versions. You can, however, use [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere), which contains all the Holo themes and is compatible with 2.1+.

Comment: If you look at my values/styles.xml which should be in use for devices with API 10 or less, I set Theme.Light (not Holo)

Comment: Yes, but Holo is for API 14 and above.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml says: "If you're developing for API level 11 and higher, you should instead use Theme.Holo or Theme.DeviceDefault"

Comment: Holo was added for API 11, see [Android 3.0 APIs](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.0.html). In Android 4 the Holo themes were guaranteed to not change from one device to another, see [Android 4.0 APIs](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html).